# error when upload file csv to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

i want to import csv file to mysql database. the upload was success. but nothing to import. I think i'm wrong in sql query. here is my query :

```
mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$filename' INTO TABLE CityBlocks FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 2 LINES (startIpNum, endIpNum, locId)") or die (mysql_error());
```

and the error is :

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' IGNORE 2 LINES (startIpNum, endIpNum, locId)' at line 2

Can you tell me where is my mistake and how to fix this problem. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have an extra " here:

ENCLOSED BY '\"'

Sorry my bad, they are enclosed by " so it is correct to escape with \.

---

LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

Have you tried modify this line to use only '\n':

LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

Also try not using the LOCAL keyword

Comment: do i need to delete the (") ?

Comment: but my error now is : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\' LINES TERMINATED BY ' ' IGNORE 2 LINES (startIpNum, endIpNum, locId)' at line 1.
that error happened when i delete the ". how to fix this? Thank You.

Comment: Yes. Try and see what happens.

Comment: I've delete the ". but now i get another error like I've said in my comment above. do you know how to fix it??

Comment: What are you using to upload? Don't you have phpMyadmin?

Comment: yes i have phpmyadmin. but i made the interface to upload csv to mysql. so the user can browse file csv to upload and insert the data to mysql. the query is like i've posted above. So how do you think?

Comment: I made some updates. Also try adding name of table before column names.

Comment: Thank You. It works. It because i delete the \r in lines terminated. Really Big thanks.